# How to integrate existing SOAP webservice (CXF) implementation into Grails application?

Tags: web-services, grails, soap, cxf

We have an existing interface and implementation for a webservice. We would like to embed this code into a Grails 2.x application. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the grails cxf plugin.

http://grails.org/plugin/cxf

You with it can do stuff like

```
import javax.jws.*
class TestService {
      static expose=['cxfjax']

      @WebResult(name="addResult")
      @WebMethod(operationName="add")
      int add(@WebParam(name="a")int a, @WebParam(name="b")int b) {
         return a + b
     }
 }
```

If your do not have groovy, but have java, then use the plugin and wire in the java services using resources.groovy or resources.xml

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply. My use case is that i have to implement a wsdl contract. I am able to create the interface using wsdl2java but after that i would like to use Grails services to implement the actual implementation. I am using the CXF plugin, but get stuck after the actual generation of the interface. I have no clue on how could implement the generated interface with Grails Services. I tried several combinations using resources.xml but no luck so far.

Comment: Does wsdl2java give you an interface like the one above?? Just move it into java folder and use it ...

Comment: I am trying to implement a very simple wsdl located on: http://docs.codehaus.org/download/attachments/85983334/currencyConverterService.wsdl?version=1&modificationDate=1212335543051

Comment: I created an implementation outside Grails and one using the cxf plugin the WSDL from the Grails plugin is missing the Request and Response types.. any clue what i am missing?

Comment: I manually copied the WebParam and WebResult from the interface to the service method. Is this the correct way?